# Splice list of date objects in Python

Tags: python, slice

Is there a simple way to splice a list of date objects:

```
spliced = sortedDates[startDate:endDate]
print spliced
```

or does this requires an enumeration?

**Example**:

```
sortedDates = [July 1 2012, July 2 2012, July 3 2012, July 4, 2012]
spliced = sortedDates[July 2 2012:July 4 2012]
```

Comment: (in python it is called slicing, not splicing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a list `sortedDates` that contains `datetime` object, and 2 `datetime` `minD` and `maxD` objects to define your boundaries:

```
filtered = [d for d in sortedDates if minD < d < maxD]
```

Or, more efficient since it takes advantage of the sorted nature of the list to use a binary search:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
filtered = sortedDates[bisect_right(sortedDates, minD):bisect_left(sortedDates, maxD)]
```

Comment: I get the following type error:  filtered = sortedDates[bisect_right(startDate, sortedDates):bisect_left(endDate, sortedDates)]
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.date' has no len()

Comment: yes, my parameters are not in the right order. fixing it now

Comment: Python list slices grab the range [start, stop), so I think this would more closely match the behavior of that: `filtered = [d for d in sortedDates if minD <= d < maxD]`

Comment: @nofinator: I just tested it using regular ints, filtering [1,2,3,4] with `2` and `4` returns `[3]`, so I think it really is `minD < d < maxD`. You'd need to use `bisect_left` for the first bound to obtain your behavior

Comment: @njzk2 True. Bisecting could only give you (start, stop). And now that I think about it, my comparison to list slices isn't really apples-to-apples. List slices are indices, but the date slices in this question are dates that could potentially be values in the list. So, yes, (start, stop) is valid, too. And whichever one is chosen, it should be documented in the code, naturally. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a range of dates by using a list comprehension:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5)
nb_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1  # + 1 because range is exclusive
splice = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(nb_days)]
```

With the example given:

```
>>> [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, nb_days)]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 0, 0)]
```

---

If you want to return a sublist of an existing range list, you can also construct it via a comprehension list, again:

```
splice = [x for x in original_list if start_date < x < end_date]
```

Comment: and if the end date is given?

Comment: actually this isn't exactly what I was asking, because this doesn't splice the list of days; this creates a new list. Is there anyway to splice the original list of dates? In any case, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` is terrific for date handling.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
dr = pd.date_range('2012-07-01', '2012-08-01')
dr[(dr >= datetime(2012,7,4)) & (dr <= datetime(2012,7,8))]
```